# Python Eve, How to enable embedding for multiple endpoint?

Tags: python, rest, eve

Embedding for `tasks_datasets` endpoint does not work, but works for `datasets`.

What am I doing wrong? And sorry for Google translator

My `settings.py`, I lowered some resources:

```
dataset_item = {
    'type': 'dict',
    'required': True,
    'schema': {
        'data': {
            'type': 'list',
            'default': [],
        },
        'attachments': {
            'type': 'list',
            'default': [],
            'schema': {
                'type': 'objectid',
                'data_relation': {
                    'resource': 'attachments',
                    'embeddable': True
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

datasets = {
    'schema': {
        'fixture': dataset_item,
        'result': dataset_item
    }
}

tasks_datasets = {
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'datasets',
        'projection': {
            'fixture': 1,
            'result': 1
        }
    },
    'url': 'tasks/<regex("[a-f0-9]{24}"):task>/datasets'
}

DOMAIN = {
    'datasets': datasets,
    'tasks_datasets': tasks_datasets
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar issue.